# Здравствуйте! Есть проблема с классом SafeMySQL

Tags: php, ооп, mysqli

Создал класс для Логина на сайте, но остановился так как появилась ошибка

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\localhost\safemysql.php on line 560

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\localhost\safemysql.php on line 560

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\localhost\safemysql.php on line 466

Мой код -

```html
<?php
require_once "../../safemysql.php";
class Login extends SafeMySql {
    private $username;
    private $password;
    function __construct() {
        $this->username=$_POST['username'];
        $this->password=$_POST['password'];
    }
    public function check(){
    if($this->username=="" || $this->password==""){
echo "Password or Username is empty.";
exit();
    }else {
        $this->getAll("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?s AND password=?s",$this->username,$this->password);
    }
}
}
if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
    header('Location: ../register.php');
}else{
    $login = new Login();
    $login->check(); 
}
?>
```

Сам класс - https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php

Вопрос - С чей стороны ошибка? С моей или со стороны класса?

Comment: Читали описание `?n`, `?s` и прочих параметров в классе?

Comment: Да, я понял что мне нужен ?s, но при нем ошибок еще больше

Comment: поэтому я после него попробовал поставить ?n и ошибок стало меньше

Comment: Ой, правда, правильный же путь - минимизировать количество ошибок путем написания неправильных конструкций, а не написать корректный код по правилам предоставленного класса

Comment: Да-да, извините... сейчас поставлю ?s и скину все остальные ошибки..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в своем классе переопределяете конструктор родителя, в котором устанавливается соединение с БД. Поэтому соединение в Вашем классе не определено
Стоит сделать

- либо передавать в свой конструктор соединения или параметры соединения (как это сделано в SafeMySql) и вызывать в своем конструкторе родительский конструктор (это решение получше)
- либо переопределить в своем классе свойство `$defaults`, прописав в него параметры соединения с базой (этот вариант похуже)

PS. логин и пароль тоже лучше передавать в конструктор и перед этим "очищать" от sql инъекций

Comment: сейчас попробую)

Comment: "очисткой" от инъекций занимается метод класса, который парсит плейсхолдеры. Если грамотно пользоваться плейсхолдерами в запросах - инъекций не будет (ну и если не использовать всякие специфические кодировки)

Comment: Ну это и понятно, тк класс так и называется SafeMySQL + в нём встречаются всем известные real_escape_string'и и тд.